# Word breaking for relative size elements

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break, css-hyphens

I've tried very hard to find a solution to this, but nothing seems to work.
The words in the location elements do not break and change lines, i' ve tried everything, word-wrap:break-all |break-word and the current edition. Nothing seems to break the long lines to smaller ones.
https://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/2431/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Best Route</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                display: inline;
                top:0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        bigcontainer
        {
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 99%;
            margin-left: 0.5%;
            margin-right: 0.5%;
            background-color: #333333;
            height: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            float: top;
        }

        map
        {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 75%;
            background-color: green;
        }

        livelocations
        {
            float: right;
            width: 25%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        livelocations h1
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0.5%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #edf0f5;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.location
        {
            background-color: #637bad;
            width: 99%;
            height: 10%;
            margin: 0.5%;
            color: #edf0f5;
            margin-top: 1%;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        div.location button
        {
            background: white url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/linecons-3/17/close-128.png) center;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            float: right;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        }

        div.location p
        {
            display: block;
            font-size: 75%;
            -webkit-hyphens: auto;
           -moz-hyphens: auto;
            -ms-hyphens: auto;
                hyphens: auto;
            float: left;
            width: 80%; 
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <bigcontainer>
        <map></map>
        <livelocations>
            <h1>Live locations</h1>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
            <div class='location'>
                <p>The support of CSS3 Hyphenation has started in Firefox 6 for the english languages.</p>
                <button></button>
            </div>
        </livelocations>
    </bigcontainer>
    <bigcontainer>
        <search><label for="autocomplete">Address</label><input placeholder="Enter address here..." id="autocomplete" type="text" size="35"></input></search>
    </bigcontainer>
</body>
```

Comment: im confused it looks like it's working to me... what's the problem?

Comment: They seem to wrap just fine for me.  Could you clarify what the desired effect is? http://i.stack.imgur.com/WFC1o.png

Comment: do you not want them to break?

Comment: I'm using Firefox and the lines keep flowing outside the location element.
I'm also testing the app in nw.js which also renders the same thing
firefox: http://img42.com/QImrU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `body` has `white-space: nowrap;` which inherits all the way down to the `p` elements... add `white-space: normal;` to them and they will wrap...